# Creating webservices using spring-mvc. One project or multiple projects

Tags: java, spring

Using spring mvc to create a restful api, Maven is build tool and tomcat with spring jars is deployment .

**Plan A**: each webservice will be its own separate war file/project ?  if required I would supply dependices as jar(s) (such as any dao's/dto's/service layer classes used in different webservices? I would share the spring jars between projects from with tomcat lib directory.

**Plan B**: Have one large project with different controllers (and subsequent request mappings for restful api) added when needed. Supply the spring dependices with project in maven.

Which is better ? I'm aware spring is not jax-rs compliant - what does this mean in practice, whats the difference if not compliant ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you want these web services to scale. For example, if your 4 GET calls are called 1 million more times per day than the 1 PUT request, then you'll want to split them out so you can load balance them more easily.

Answer (score 1):

The first option is good if you might deploy to different boxes in the future, for example on a high traffic site you may want each API in a separate machine or cluster. Otherwise it's just a pain so for small projects just put it all in one war file.

Comment: why is it a pain ?

Comment: its just extra setup and complexity for nothing. You'd be creating a multi-pom project with dependencies between the projects. But all the jars and wars would ultimately deploy on one tomcat box. So it makes more sense to deploy as a single war unless there's a compelling reason to split it up (e.g. the endpoints are going to deploy to different boxes).